# Optimize rmultinomial in a map2 function to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

We want to distribute the number of flights on 3 different levels (V1, V2, V3) using a multinomilal law. But the following code takes a lot of time for 10 million lines. Is there a way to optimize the map2? Probably going through datatable?
Note that we use map2 to apply the proba vector line by line.

### Starting data

```
| number_total_flights| 
|:------------------ :|
| 3                   |
| 4                   |
| 5                   |
```

### Expected result

```
| number_total_flights | V1  | V2  | V3  |
|:-------------------- |:---:|:---:|----:|
| 3                    | 0   | 0   | 3   |
| 4                    | 2   | 1   | 1   |
| 5                    | 1   | 1   | 3   |
```

### Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

base <- structure(list(
  number_total_flights = c(3L, 4L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

proba <- list(
  structure(c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)),
  structure(c(0.5, 0.2, 0.3), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)),
  structure(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)))
```

### Function treatment

```
# Calling by map2
distrib_for_each_level <- function(nb_flights, prob){
  level <- t(rmultinom(n=1, size=nb_flights, prob=prob))
}

# Function using map2
adding_levels <- function (base, proba){
  list_levels <- map2(base$number_total_flights, proba, distrib_for_each_year) %>%
    map(as.data.frame) %>% rbindlist()
  base <- base %>% cbind(list_levels)
}
```

### Result

```
base_with_levels <- adding_levels(base, proba)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping over the 10 million cases, it would be faster to loop over the categories.  You can use `rbinom()` for that, and it is vectorized.  The idea is that the result of the first category in a multinomial is a binomial with the category probability; the result in the second category is a binomial using the remaining probability and remaining count, etc.

I can't read your code (tidyverse code is clever but unreadable!), so I'll post completely new code to illustrate.  This takes a few seconds to evaluate:

```r
n <- 10000000 # number of cases
m <- 3        # number of categories

probs <- matrix(runif(n*m), n, m)
probs <- probs/rowSums(probs) # Fake multinomial probabilities

counts <- rpois(n, 3)            # Fake multinomial counts

result <- matrix(NA, n, m)    # Result matrix
for (i in 1:(m-1)) {
  prob <- probs[, i]/rowSums(probs[, i:m]) # probability of next column
  count <- counts - rowSums(result, na.rm = TRUE) # remaining count
  result[, i] <- rbinom(n, count, prob)
}
result[, m] <- counts - rowSums(result, na.rm = TRUE)
head(result)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    3    0
#> [2,]    0    3    0
#> [3,]    1    0    1
#> [4,]    1    0    1
#> [5,]    1    2    0
#> [6,]    0    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You could probably speed it up a bit more by changing the rowSums calls to only add up the right columns instead of ignoring NAs, but I was lazy.

Comment: I don't see where the rmultinom function is used, have you created something similar?
Because I am looking for a simple way to iterate over the rows of a data.table to apply the rmultino function to it.

Comment: I am not using it, I am using `rbinom` as described.  Using `rmultinom` is going to be very slow, because it is not vectorized.  You'll need to call it 10 million times, versus calling `rbinom` twice.  The result follows the same multinomial distribution.

Comment: It seems to be the correct answer, but I can't manage to adapt your code with my sample data used in the post. My prob data are in 3 columns, yours is in one column.

Comment: No, `probs` has 3 columns.

Comment: I think the real problem here is that you are too inflexible in deciding how to do what you want.  You set things up so they work with `map2` etc, when there are much more natural (and faster!) data structures available.